# How to customize function parameter errors(c++)

Tags: c++

I wrote a function that requires two parameters, but I don't want those two parameters to be 0.

I want to make the compiler know that those two parameters cannot be 0 through some ways, otherwise the editor will report an error in the form of "red wavy line".

I refer to "custom exception class" to solve this problem, but I find this method does not work.

If there are someone knows how to do , I will be very happy, because it takes me a whole day

For example:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int Fuction(int i , int j){  

    //code
}

int main(){
    Funciton(1,1);
    Funciton(0,0);
    //I don't want i or j is zero
    //But if they are still zero , The program will still work normally
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Within the rules of C++ there's nothing to prevent normal function arguments from being zero, there's no "positive and non-zero integer" type. It's also very hard to do static flow analysis of code to reliably detect this, and in some cases it's even impossible (think user input).

Comment: It's going to take longer than a day. What you are asking for is impossible. You are confusing compile time (when you what the error to show) with run time, which is the only time your code can check whether a parameter is zero. What you are asking for *might* be possible if you turn your function into a template function, but until we see some code it's impossible to tell if that is feasible.

Comment: *I don't want i or j is zero* and *But if they are still zero , The program will still work normally* This is very confusing.

Comment: @Mplan Will this function ever be called with a variable, like `x = ...; y = ...; Fuction(x, y)`?

Comment: @john Yes......

Comment: @Mplan Then you are fundamentally confused. The compiler (at compile time) cannot possibly know what the value of a variable is (at run time).

Comment: @john I know,so my idea is impossible to come true?

Comment: @Mplan I'm afraid so. Your **program** can report an error, but you can't make the **compiler** report an error.

Comment: Okay John gave me the answer .
That is imposible to come true.
I just want to ask if my idea can be realized
Now I know, so it's okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no integer type without a `0`. However, you can provoke a compiler error by introducing a conversion to a pointer type. Its a bit hacky, but achieves what you want (I think) for a literal `0`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct from_int {
    int value;
    from_int(int value) : value(value) {}
};

struct non_zero {
    int value;
    non_zero(int*) = delete;
    non_zero(from_int f) : value(f.value) {}
};

void bar(non_zero n) {
    int i = n.value; // cannot be 0
}

int main() {
    bar(non_zero(42));
    //bar(non_zero(0)); // compiler error
}
```

`bar` is the function that cannot be called with a `0` parameter. `0` can be converted to a pointer but that constructor has no definition. Any other `int` will pick the other constructor. Though it requires the caller to explicitly construct a `non_zero` because only one user defined conversion is taken into account.

Note that this only works for a literal `0`. There is no error when you pass a `0` to this function:

```
void moo(int x){
    bar(non_zero(x));
}
```

Thats why it should be considered as a hack. Though, in general it is not possible to trigger a compiler error based on the value of `x` which is only known at runtime.

If you want to throw an exception, thats a whole different story. You'd simply add a check in the function:

```
if (i == 0) throw my_custom_exception{"some error message"};
```

Comment: I already said you were a genius.

Comment: Although it's not what I want, it can still meet my needs

Comment: @Mplan if thats not what you want then i am clueless. I mention both: error at build time and runtime error, whats the third option you want?

Comment: Error when typing code

Comment: @Mplan that depends on what Code Analysis tool your IDE is using, which you didnt mention. Such tools also only report errors that your compiler can report. If it is clever enough it will realize that there is no definition for `non_zero(int*)` and report it as error.

Comment: @Mplan as I said before, you are confusing some things here: "I want to make the compiler know that those two parameters cannot be 0 through some ways, otherwise the editor will report an error in the form of "red wavy line". I refer to "custom exception class" to solve this problem". The squiggly lines in your editor are not from the compiler and an excpetion is thrown at runtime only.

Comment: you let me see the light suddenly

Comment: If you change to `non_zero(int*) = delete;` you will turn the linker error into a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only MSVC you can also take a look at Structured Annotation Language (SAL). It is described on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects).

For your case you might be interested in `_In_range_(lb,ub)`. An example would be:

```
void f(_In_range_(1,300) int a, _In_range_(1, 2147483647) int b);
```

Please note that this will not prohibit calling `f(0, 0)` but code analysis will trigger a warning. That warning will be triggered also in cases where you call `f(x,x)` and the compiler knows that `x` is zero.

In the past I liked to use SAL as it makes the interface clearer and can help reveal errors because the compiler can check more semantics. But now with modern C++ und the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) I am trying to follow the guidelines and so normally I don't need SAL anymore.